# Fixing Syntax Error, on my Script Editor

Tags: javascript

```js
function sendEmails(e){
     var UserName = e.values[3];
     var UserEmail = e.values[5];
     var date = e.values[0];
     var pin = e.values[4];
     var subject = "[LFR] Application Succeed!";
     var bodymessage = "Hi" + UserName + "for sending in your job application."
<br>
    <br> + "The following is your Purchase Log Pin"
        <br> + pin;
     var emailsent = "Email Sent";
     var isEmailsent = e.values[6];
  if (isEmailsent ! = emailsent);
       
       
    MailApp.sendEmail(UserEmail, subject, bodymessage); 
     
}
```

The error message always shows, "Illegally formed XML syntax. (line 18, file "Code"). Someone please help me to fix it!

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
var bodymessage = "Hi" + UserName + "for sending in your job application."
<br>
    <br> + "The following is your Purchase Log Pin"
        <br> + pin;
```

to

```
var bodymessage = "Hi" + UserName + "for sending in your job application.<br>   <br>The following is your Purchase Log Pin<br>" + pin;
```

bascially, your string is not formed correctly

Also,

remove `;` after the if statement

```
if (isEmailsent ! = emailsent)
{
  MailApp.sendEmail(UserEmail, subject, bodymessage); 
}
```

Comment: Hello, now the error is: Missing ) after condition. (line 10, file "Code").
Which is in the line if (isEmailsent ! = emailsent);

Comment: @MikoChan yes, that too. use http://jshint.com/ for checking the quality of your code always.

Comment: So how do I fix the errors on my JS? JShint says "Expected a conditional expression and instead saw an assignment" on my 'if' statement, but how do I change to conditional expression?

Comment: @MikoChan check on jshint after making the changes I have suggested